# Postgresql: Issue with daylight saving and interval

Tags: postgresql

In Postgresql I use `interval` to detect if two timestamps differs by less than 1 month,
the problem is that with daylight saving, there's a mismatch of 1 hour.
For example considering

```
SELECT
'2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-01-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-06-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months'
;
```

we can clearly see that the check fails for `2023-04-01` and `2023-03-01`, because in that period daylight saving goes on.
To me the problem seems that `interval` only increases the timestamp by 1 month, without considering the daylight saving.
I mean `'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months'` (or the equivalent `'2023-03-01 15:00:00 America/Chicago'::timestamptz + interval '1 months'`) should increase `2023-03-01` by one month, but should also decrease the hour by 1, but it doesn't.

Is there any way to make `interval` daylight saving aware?

I'm on postgres 11.16 if that matters, but I can't upgrade it in case.

Comment: I am not sure about `interval`; But, If this is your real data (Which is in consistent format) using some other date functions it should be possible; Well, A Nice Question

Comment: what shall we see when we run your code https://dbfiddle.uk/sdTJtja_

Comment: @nbk
I'm not sure on how dbfiddle.uk works.
When I run the query I get
false false true false false
like in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m6nS56AzFrFpbZUAh2bGtz/0
While I'd expect all false, if there were no issues with daylight saving.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems that I just need to localise to the time zone after increasing with interval,
so

```
SELECT
'2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-01-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months',
'2023-06-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months'
;
```

becomes

```
SELECT
'2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < ('2023-01-01 15:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 months') at time zone 'America/Chicago',
'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < ('2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 months') at time zone 'America/Chicago',
'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < ('2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 months') at time zone 'America/Chicago',
'2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < ('2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 months') at time zone 'America/Chicago',
'2023-06-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < ('2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp + interval '1 months') at time zone 'America/Chicago'
;
```

I'll have to double check if I'm missing some details/edge case, but it might just be as simple as that.

Comment: Or see update to my answer where I rotate to `UTC` to deal with time shift.

Answer (score 0):

[Datetimes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

> Fractional parts of weeks and days are computed to be an integer number of days and microseconds, assuming 30 days per month and 24 hours per day, e.g., '1.75 months' becomes 1 mon 22 days 12:00:00.

So:

```
select '30 days'::interval = '1 month'::interval;
t

select '2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' - '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' ;

30 days 23:00:00

select '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + '1 month'::interval ;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 2023-04-01 13:00:00-07
```

**UPDATE**

When in doubt use `UTC`:

```
SELECT
'2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' < ('2023-01-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC'+ interval '1 months'),
'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' < ('2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' + interval '1 months'),
'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' < ('2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' + interval '1 months'),
'2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' < ('2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' + interval '1 months'),
'2023-06-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' < ('2023-05-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' at time zone 'UTC' + interval '1 months')
;

 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----------
 f        | f        | t        | f        | f
```

Comment: It comes down to what you want `1 month` to be? Much like a `day` considered is taken to be a)  A  4 hour period  b) The time from Midnight to just before Midnight of next day, month has many definitions. Add a more detailed description of what you want the interval comparison to be as update to your question.

Comment: `'1 month'::interval` alone is 30 days, but I cannot re-write my check from 
`'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' + interval '1 months'`
to
`'2023-04-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' - '2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < interval '1 months'`
otherwise even the difference between `'2023-04-01 10:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago'` and`'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago'` is not seen as less than 1 month.

Comment: Even worse it would not work with February that is shorter:
`SELECT
'2023-03-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' - '2023-02-01 15:00:00'::timestamp at time zone 'America/Chicago' < interval '1 months';` returns true.

I need some function that when incrementing (or decrementing a timestamp)
by a month, updates also the time accordingly to the daylight saving (if it switched to on or off during that month).